# How to secure a box on my window's exterior sill?

Tags: exterior, sill

Below is a picture of how the exterior sill of my window looks like.

I want to put some kind of a small box/container on the exterior sill and I want to ensure that it is secure and doesn't fall off the window. The window opens towards the inside.

Additionally, I also want to ask if it is possible to do it securely without damaging the exterior of the building with bolts or nails.

I have tried sometimes placing small pots on the exterior sill and they fit nicely, but only for a short time, as I'm afraid that they could fall.

I was thinking of placing some kind of a barrier?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What will be in said box; how heavy will it be? And just to clarify, the exterior is smooth, no moldings or grooves/edges whatsoever?

Comment: I want to keep some vegetables or fruites inside, so I'd say it would be around 2 kg max.